# Chef: No candidate version available for mod_security2 for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, mod-security, mod-security2

I get error `Chef: No candidate version available for mod_security2` while including `package mod_security` or `package mod_security2`

Here is snipped stacktrace:

```
       * No candidate version available for mod_security2
       ================================================================================
       Error executing action `install` on resource 'apt_package[mod_security2]'
       ================================================================================

       Chef::Exceptions::Package
       -------------------------
       No candidate version available for mod_security2

       Resource Declaration:
       ---------------------
       # In <snipped>

        13: package 'mod_security2'
        14: 

       Compiled Resource:
       ------------------
       # Declared in <snipped> `from_file'

       apt_package("mod_security2") do
         package_name "mod_security2"
         action [:install]
         default_guard_interpreter :default
         declared_type :package
         cookbook_name "mod_secure"
         recipe_name "default"
       end

       System Info:
       ------------
       chef_version=13.0.118
       platform=ubuntu
       platform_version=16.04
       ruby=ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
       program_name=chef-client worker: ppid=16061;start=17:30:57;
       executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client
```

Answer (score 2):

This means there is no version of the package available in apt. You might be missing an `apt-get update`. In your base recipe or whatever the closest you have to that is add `apt_update`.

Comment: That's not the issue as as recipe include `apt_update`

Comment: Then are you sure the package exists?

Comment: By default it's `libapache2-mod-security2` on Ubuntu/Debian.